# Prompt numbers while value=-1

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to prompt some number while the user not gonna write "-1".If he write "-1",i have to print out,which 3 numbers were the largest.I know that i have to store these numbers in string,and after that i should use the math.max function.Here is my last attemp:

```
function largestnumbers()
{
do
{
    var a = Number(prompt("Enter some numbers"));
}
while(a!=-1);

if(a==-1)
{
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var str = document.getElementById("str");
    a.innerHTML=str;
 }
 }
```

Comment: *"I know that i have to store these numbers in string"*: it is better to store them in an array.

Comment: store in an array... then use the `Math.max.apply(null, array)`

Comment: The problem right now is that you don't store the other numbers which are !=-1 anywhere. They're just gone.

Comment: Have a look at [Prompt user to Input Numbers in Array and then Sum it using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011567/prompt-user-to-input-numbers-in-array-and-then-sum-it-using-javascript).

Comment: It might be better to use Array.prototype.sort, then get the last 3 indices than to use Math.max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not 'remembering' the items, use an array to keep the items, and check the latest index for the desired number.

Then, after the while loop, you can parse the result;

```js
function largestnumbers() {

    // Array to hold all numbers
    let arr = [ ];

    // While 
    // arr is empty
    // or, last item in array isn't -1
    while (arr.length === 0 || arr[arr.length - 1] !== -1) {

        // Ask again
        arr.push(Number(prompt("Enter some numbers")));
    }

    // After while, last item in arr is now -1
    // Sort the array
    arr.sort().reverse();
    
    // Show 3 highest numbers in result
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = arr.slice(0, 3).join('<br />');
}
largestnumbers();
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: This answer coerces the elements to strings, so input like [1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 12] will fail. Use `sort((a, b) => b - a)` instead of `sort().reverse()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function largestnumbers() {
        let array = []
        let number;
        do
        {
             number = Number(prompt("Enter some numbers")) || -1;
             if(number == -1) 
                break;
             else
                array.push(number)
        }while(number != -1)
        
        array.sort((a,b)=>b-a);

        document.write(array.slice(0, 3).join(','))
    }
    largestnumbers();
```